# Prove the equivalence of an upper bounded non empty set

Tags: calculus, analysis

Be $M \subseteq\mathbb{R}$ non empty and upper boundend. Show for $s \in \mathbb{R}$ the following equivalence:

$ s = \sup M  \Longleftrightarrow$  $s$ is an upper bound of $M$ and there exists a sequennce $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $a_n \in S$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ a_n = s$

It's clear to me that I have to show the two directons:

$\rightarrow$ my idea:  It is clear that, if $s=\sup m$, then $s$ is an upper bound of $M$. Take $\varepsilon \gt 0$. Since $s$ is the least upper bound of $M, s−\varepsilon$ is not an upper bound of $M$, which means that there is a $x \in A$ such that $x\geq s−\varepsilon$.
Actually I have no clue how can I continue it and I even don't know the $\leftarrow$ direction.
I appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: I think the statement on the right should be $s$ is *an* upper bound of $M$ (not *the* upper bound) and there exists a sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$ *with* $a_n \in S$ for every $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=s$.

Comment: You also need $a_n \in S$, which isn't part of your problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the "$\Rightarrow$" direction, consider values of $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{n}$, and for each $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{n}$ find the corresponding $x_n$ as you did. The the sequence of these $(x_n)$ is what you want (but you still need to justify this claim).

For the opposite "$\Leftarrow$" direction, first note that since $s$ is an upper bound for $M$ and since all $a_n\in M$ (not "$S$", which seems to be a typo in your post), then all $a_n\leqslant s$. Now let's show that for any $\varepsilon>0$, $s-\varepsilon$ is not an upper bound for $M$. To that end, apply the definition of the limit of a sequence to the given limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=s$ and this value of $\varepsilon$.